# API GW V2 HTTP API and legacy lambda authorizer

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to integrate API GW v2 HTTP API with legacy (payload version 1.0) custom lambda authorizer. It's able to invoke the custom lambda authorizer but getting below response ($context.authorizer.error) in gateway logs with 500 status ($context.authorizer.status https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-logging-variables.html)-

`The response from the Lambda Authorizer function doesn't match the format that API Gateway expects. Invalid value for 'context'`

Which indicates that it's not abiding to the response format as mentioned here-
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-lambda-authorizer.html#http-api-lambda-authorizer.payload-format-response

But same legacy lambda is working fine with API GW v1 REST APIs. Also cannot enable the execution logs like REST API so not able to see the actual response returned by lambda if by any chance it's not returning the correct response but i doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

So problem seems to be API GW HTTP API doesn't like null values in context variable from Lambda authorizer. For now going to suppress the null values but ideally API GW should handle the null values gracefully. Another problem is it seems to be timing out in case time taken is more than 10 secs by Lambda authorizer but there's no way timeout can be configured for lambda authorizer.